# Scan for Open ports

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I tried to scan for open ports on my ip using following snippet, it is taking more than 20 mins to complete but I need things to be done in less than a minute.

```
- (void)scanForOpenPorts
{
    struct hostent *host;
    int err, i, sock;
    char hostname[100] = "192.168.1.17";
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    
    //Initialise the sockaddr_in structure
    memcpy((char*)&sa , "" , sizeof sa);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    //direct ip address, use it
    if(isdigit(hostname[0]))
    {
        printf("Doing inet_addr...");
        sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);
        printf("Done\n");
    }
    //Resolve hostname to ip address
    else if( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Doing gethostbyname...");
        memcpy((char*)&sa.sin_addr , (char*)host->h_addr , sizeof sa.sin_addr);
        printf("Done\n");
    }
    else
    {
        herror(hostname);
        exit(2);
    }
    
    //Start the port scan loop
    printf("Starting the portscan loop : \n");
    
    NSLog(@"Start Time: %@", [NSDate date]);
    
    for(i = 0; i <= 65536; i++)
    {
        //Fill in the port number
        sa.sin_port = htons(i);
        //Create a socket of type internet
        sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
        
        //Check whether socket created fine or not
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("\nSocket");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Connect using that socket and sockaddr structure
        err = connect(sock , (struct sockaddr*)&sa , sizeof sa);
        
        //not connected
        if( err < 0 )
        {
            //printf("%s %-5d %s\r" , hostname , i, strerror(errno));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        //connected
        else
        {
            printf("%-5d open\n",  i);
        }
        
        close(sock);
    }
    
    NSLog(@"End Time: %@", [NSDate date]);
    
    printf("\r");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: If that is running code, it is off-topic on SO. This is not a code-review site. And that is no C code! Do not add C tag for non-C code.

Comment: you have C syntax errors, and things like your memcpy don't make sense; I don't have much trust you really even understand what you're trying to do. I humbly suggest you start to learn C before you do something as complex as this.

Comment: @Olaf suggest it is *supposed* to be C ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `NSLog(@"Start Time: %@", [NSDate date])`? Anyway, this is .OT

Comment: @Olaf I've seen that. *could* be some strange preprocessing (like e.g. Qt's `moc` -- ok, you could argue this isn't C++ any more, too, of course) and yes, it's OT (the question, too). where's the "this belongs on CR" close reason? ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Maybe, but as it will not compile as std C, it is not. And OP tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @Olaf moc was an example as a widely used *extension* to C++. But in fact, it doesn't matter, as this question doesn't really belong here.

Comment: Questions related to code reviews belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You are using sockets in blocking mode, and testing the ports one at a time in a serial manner with no timeout on `connect()`.  So, of course it is going to take a long time to scan such a large range of ports.  You need to parallelize your code so you can connect to multiple ports at the same time, reducing the time it takes to scan the range of ports.

Use non-blocking sockets, with `select()` or `poll()` or equivalent providing a timeout for `connect()` (most platforms do not provide a way to specify a timeout for `connect()` in blocking mode, so you are subject to the socket stack's internal timeout).

Have multiple sockets connecting to a different port at the same time, either in individual worker threads, or at least in a `select()`/`poll()` loop.

Run a limited number of connects at any given time, so as not to overwhelm the device or the network.  Start a few connects to begin.  When any given socket has finished connecting to its current port, have that thread/slot choose the next available port, close+recreate its socket if needed, and try again.  Repeat as needed until the range of ports has been exhausted.

Each time `connect()` fails without a timeout, you can reuse that same socket for the next `connect()`, you do not need to `close()` it.  But, if `connect()` succeeds, or fails with a timeout, you have to to `close()` that socket and create a new one for the next `connect()`.